# Httpcontext.current.session becoming null

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, httpcontext

Httpcontext.current.session becoming null in local code, session not expired still in active and I didn't clear session manually when click on button controller will receive post request and after authenticating user setting user details in httpcontext.current.session, after setting if I send another post request all values are becoming null

```
internal class AspDotNet : Base
    {
        internal AspDotNet(String key)
            : base(key)
        {

        }

        internal override void Set(Object value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
            HttpContext.Current.Session[base.Key] = value;
        }

        internal override Object Get()
        {
           
                this.Value = HttpContext.Current.Session[base.Key];
                return this.Value;
           
        }

        internal override void Remove()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(base.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i believe you need to create a static class for keeping session value. Can you share your code for accesing session value.

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this. I believe static class will work for you.

```
public static class SessionPersiter
{
    public static int? UserID
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                return (Int32?)null;

            var sessionData = HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonConstants.UserIDSessionKey];
            if (sessionData == null)
                return (Int32?)null;
            return (int)sessionData;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonConstants.UserIDSessionKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public static UserDTO AuthenticatedUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                return null;

            var sessionData = HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonConstants.AuthenticatedUserKey];
            if (sessionData == null)
                return null;
            return (UserDTO)sessionData;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonConstants.AuthenticatedUserKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public static long? LastLoginID
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                return (long?)null;

            var sessionData = HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonConstants.LastLoginIDSessionKey];
            if (sessionData == null)
                return (long?)null;
            return (long)sessionData;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonConstants.LastLoginIDSessionKey] = value;
        }
    }
    }
```

and call like this

```
var userToken =  SessionPersiter.AuthenticatedUser.Token;
```